# Hello! How to pull data from localStorage in Vue.js and render on the page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

The task is to integrate the cart as a separate component in Vuejs into a finished project, written not in Vuejs. There is a part of a function for adding an item to the cart, which stores data in localStorage.

```
for (let i = 0; i < addToCartBtns.length; i++) {
  addToCartBtns[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    notification.classList.add("notification--opened");
    setTimeout(closeNotification, 4000);
    qtyChanger(products[i]);
  });
}

function qtyChanger(product) {
  let productQty= localStorage.getItem('qty');

  productQty= parseInt(productQty);

  if(productQty) {
    localStorage.setItem("qty", productQty + parseInt(input.value));
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("qty", input.value);
    activateCart();
  } 
  setItems(product);
  
}

function setItems(product) {
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
  if (cartItems !== null) {
    if (cartItems[product.id] == undefined) {  
      cartItems = {
        ...cartItems,
        [product.id]: product
      }
    }
      cartItems[product.id].qty += parseInt(input.value);
    } else {
      product.qty = parseInt(input.value);
      cartItems = {
        [product.id]: product
      };
    }

  localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}

function closeNotification() {
    if (notification.classList.contains("notification--opened")) {
      notification.classList.remove("notification--opened")
    }
}

function onLoadProductQty() {
  let productQty = localStorage.getItem("qty");

  if(productQty) {
    activateCart()
  }
}

onLoadProductQty();
```

this is my store.js file in a vue cart, where I'm trying to get localStorage data

```
import {
  createApp
} from 'vue';

import {
  createStore
} from 'vuex';

let storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productsInCart"));

let store = createStore({
  state: {
    products: storage ? storage : []
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_TO_LOCALSTORAGE: (state, products) => {
      state.products = products;
    },
    CHANGE_LOCALSTORAGE: (state, products) => {
      state.products = products;
      localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(products));
    },
     ....
  },
  actions: {
    SET_PRODUCTS_TO_LOCALSTORAGE({ commit, products }) {
      commit("SET_TO_LOCALSTORAGE", products);
      commit("ACTIVATE_CART");
    },

....
    CHANGE_STATE_LOCALSTORAGE({ commit }) {
      commit("CHANGE_LOCALSTORAGE");
    }
  },
  getters: {
    PRODUCTS(state) {
      return state.products;
    }
  }
});

const app = createApp({});
app.use(store);

export default store;
```

And here I am trying to call loading from store.js

```
<template>
<div 
  class="cells" 
  v-if=" PRODUCTS && PRODUCTS.length">
  <div class="cell cell-xl-8">
    <cart/>
  </div>
  <cart-form/>
</div>
<div class="page-message" v-else>
  
    .......

</template>
<script>
import cart from './components/cart.vue'

import cartForm from './components/cart-form.vue'
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default {
  components: { cartForm, cart },
  name: "app",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'PRODUCTS'
    ])
  },
   methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'SET_PRODUCTS_TO_LOCALSTORAGE'

    ])
   },
  mounted() {
    this.SET_PRODUCTS_TO_LOCALSTORAGE()
  }
}
</script>
```

please, tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: Hey Mary, I haven't used VUE, but why doesn't SET_TO_LOCALSTORAGE call localStorage.setItem?

And why doesn't commit("CHANGE_LOCALSTORAGE") also take products like it's signature? Looks like it's committing undefined to storage.

Comment: Why are you calling 'SET_PRODUCTS_TO_LOCALSTORAGE' without data on mounted? This will fire whenever your Component is mounted, and not sending data will result in `commit("SET_TO_LOCALSTORAGE", products);` and products being `undefined`

Comment: when I am calling :  mounted() {
    this.SET_PRODUCTS_TO_LOCALSTORAGE(producrs)
  } this give an arror in console : "products is not defined"